# can we concat columnname with date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have columnname [Net Volume 2015-10].
can i use in select statement like

```
select Table.[concat ('Net Volume ' , CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -( DAY(DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 2)) )
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL to do this. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute dynamic SQL  like this :

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Query = 'Select Table.[' + concat ('Net Volume ' , YEAR(GETDATE()),'-',MONTH(GETDATE())) + '] FROM Table Where ...'

SELECT @Query


EXEC(@Query)
```